# Low end cisco switch with 'regular' CLI?

Tags: cisco

Looking for a good low end cisco switch for access layer at a branch office, it needs:
+ to utilize the standard CLI interfaces / IOS setups - no SMB solutions
+ 24 1GB copper ports, with some sort of SFP/GBIC expansion module for uplinks
+ to be at/near/or under 1k

We currently have two HP ProCurve's (unsure of the model at this time).  Current bid from management is a low end HP switch (SMB) but I'd really like to get our environment consistently Cisco.  Trying to stay under 1k new for each device.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any other requirements you have? No PoE, and you don't need layer 3? If management is looking at SMB products, is used equipment an option?

Comment: If I can come at them with some suggestions around the same pricepoint on a refurbished unit, they may be amible.  Any suggestions basing pricing off of refurbished?  - and no, no other req's like POE.

Comment: Your IOS options are basically EOS'd gray WS-C2960G-24TC-L or WS-C2960S-24TS-S or WS-C2960X-24TS-LL. If you're buying new device, WS-C2960X-24TS-LL is only sane option. If you're buying one new unit from channel partner, typical GPL discount level is about 40%, which pegs the 2960X pretty much 1000USD flat. If you have need for large number of units, you should get DealID (DID) from Cisco with special discount, this could be anything from 70-90%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to hit that price point with those requirements. A 2960X will meet those requirements at a 2.5kish price point.

I would stick with HP if your price point is 1k. The ProCurve line works well and has a lifetime warranty. Anytime I cannot get the funds for Cisco, that is my backup. Though I usually opt for the 2910al ProCurves which are 2.5k or so new.

EDIT: Some Cisco options a bit above 1k...

- 2960X-24TS-L 1600USD
- 2960X-24TS-LL 1300USD

You will want to look at what limitations the Lan Lite model has (LL).

Comment: And they're permanently non-upgradeable, as opposed to Cisco's older model.

Comment: Your prices are incorrect GPL is WS-C2960X-24TS-LL 1895USD and WS-C2960X-24TS-L 2395USD. @chrylis 2960S cannot be upgraded either, so you'd really need to go EOL to get upgradebility. It's not because Cisco is trying to be evil, it's because the HW is different.

Comment: Those were off CDW, no special discount.

Answer (score 1):

A 2960S-24TS-S meets those requirements and depending on your discount level it should be in the neighborhood of $1k

Comment: For 1GE use, there is no point buying 2960S, next-gen replacement 2960X costs same. That is SKU WS-C2960S-24TS-S and WS-C2960X-24TS-LL both are 1895USD and X is superior device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but like ytti said, we are now looking at the 2960X-24TS-LL!